# Stop the creation of FDC file in IBM MQ or create it at desired location

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I have an application which creates xmsffdc*.FDC ( replace * by some number ) . Not i want to stop creation of this FDC file as due to an issue there can be thousands of it generated which would fill space and create clean up issues too.

1. My preferred way is to create this FDC file to a desired location such as
   on a different mount ( so that disk where process collects data do not get impacted ) or
2. To stop the creation of FDC file using some environment file.

What are the ways to accomplish 1 and 2 ? Note i am using IBM MQ7.5 and 8.0 client version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in [IBM Knowledge Center: FFDC configuration for XMS .NET applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_ctrouble_ffdc_net.htm)

> By default, all FFDC files are written to the current directory.
> However, if required, you can specify a different directory by
> changing `ffdcDirectory` in the `Trace` section of the application
> configuration file. In the following example, all trace files are
> logged to the directory `c:\client\ffdc`:.
>
> ```
> <IBM.XMS>
>      <Trace ffdc=true ffdcDirectory="c:\client\ffdc"/>
> </IBM.XMS>
> ```
>
> You can disable them by setting `FFDC` to `false` in
> the `Trace` section of the application configuration file.